# Рассылка сообщения через его URL

Tags: python, telegram, sendmessage

Написал скрипт для рассылки в телеграме и хочу улучшить. В телеграмме, на каждое сообщение в канале есть своя ссылка и я хочу чтобы содержимое(то есть текст) этой ссылки рассылалось. Не могу понять как это записать в коде. Прошу ваших советов.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

print('User-Bot started')

users = '...'


api_id = ...

api_hash = '...'


with TelegramClient('',api_id, api_hash) as client:

 client.send_message(users, 'Тут хочется отправлять сообщение, котороe будет взято ссылкой из канала')
```